# how to provide a input for Vec<u64> in solana playground ide

Tags: solana-program, anchor-lang

I wanted to input for Vec in solana playground ide

[image]

can anyone help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can input `Vec<u64>` as array of numbers.

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Yes, i got it 
Can you if iam having a struct: data{task_id: u64, task_program_id: String }

If i take above struct as input like task_details: Vec<data>

how can i provide inputs parameters for these

Comment: You can pass it as JSON. Example: `[{"taskId": 1, "taskProgramId": "abc"}]`. Notice that properties are camelCase.

Comment: Thanks @acheron
It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

u can try

struct data{
task_id: u64,
task_program_id :String}

let mut data_vec :Vec = Vec::new();
let data1 = data{task_id:10,task_program_id:String::from("dv47gvewwrbnjjt4eer5")};

data_vec.push(data1);